# MPI:point-to-point blocking (MPI_Send & MPI_Recv)

Tags: mpi

I'm a little bit confused about MPI point-to-point blocking modes.
now i have the following code.

```
y = id;
j = id - 1;
if(j<0) j = p -1;

k = id + 1;
if(k>p-1) k = 0;

MPI_Recv(&x, 1, MPI_INT, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
MPI_Send(&y, 1, MPI_INT, j, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

z = x + y;
```

That will be blocked as MPI_Recv is a blocking function, but when i change the order to call MPI_Send first everything goes ok and i do not know the reason.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Send()` blocks until the send buffer can be reused.

from a pragmatic point of view, `MPI_Send()` returns immediatly if the message is short enough, and otherwise, blocks until a matching `MPI_Recv()` is posted.
this is a general behavior, but you should not rely on that.

in this case, your best option is to use a single `MPI_Sendrecv()` call instead of two blocking send/recv calls

an other option is to
`MPI_Irecv(); MPI_Send(); MPI_Wait();`

Comment: Ok now why would the program execute normally and not being blocked when i change the order and MPI_Send can return immediately

Comment: if you `MPI_Recv()` first, your program will hang forever.
if you `MPI_Send()` first, and the message is short enough, then it is sent, and the matching `MPI_Recv()` will complete.
makes sense ?